# Exclude div jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
    <a href="#">
    <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="JEDEN" style="width: 33px; height: 12px;">
    <div class="menu-button-desc" style="padding-left: 3.80049px;"></div>
    </a>
</li>
```

---

```
spec.find($(".sub-menu li:not(:contains('pic-sub'), :contains('title-sub'), div.menu-button-desc)")).clone().prependTo("#sub-menu ul");
```

I need to exclude **div.menu-button-desc**. Everything else works fine. I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select the #menu-item-43 element, it already has that div.menu-button-desc as a child. What you want to do is clone the whole node, drill down to the element you want gone, .remove() it, then .end() to get back to your cloned element without the "problem child".

You also have some funky things going on w/ combining .find and another toplevel selector ($()), and I think your selector string is mostly not doing anything. You don't want the selector to have all the logic, it's just a starting point for then traversing and manipulating. Here's my best guess for what you're going for:

```
spec.find(".sub-menu li").clone()
  .find(".menu-button-desc").remove()
  .end().prependTo("#sub-menu ul");
```

Comment: This code is in - if () {}, i needed $(this) from click selector. Your alternative way works just fine if i don't find any other way i will stay with this. Thanks !